# How to generate GIS Maps without any browser specific library?

Tags: html, node.js, gis, scheduler

I need to generate a GIS map showing some points and polygons. This map generation process has to run in the background so that every day at a certain time of the day a map is made and stored at a certain location in the file system.

I don't think leaflet can be used for this as it runs on the browser.
Not sure how will this happen in QGIS also....any light in this direction will be helpful.

My requirement is to generate a HTML report which contains a map. I cannot do it on the browser because the user will not use the browser and want the report to be inn his mailbox every day automatically.

I will be using node js to generate HTML.

How can this be achieved? Please save my life.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use something like [phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) to perform what is essentially a screen capture of the map you generate in a web page that is 'displayed' on a headless, off-screen web page. What sort of map server you use to generate the maps is up to you; but that would let you capture a browser view of the map and re-package it in a PDF or an image that is embedded in an email.

Make that PDF or image a GeoPDF or a GeoTIFF or example and the result would retain some geospatial aspects instead of being a dumb screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something capable of delivering a map tiling service (like wms) which you can then query server-side and piece together the tiles.  I've had good luck with geoserver (http://geoserver.org/) but there are other solutions as well.  I'm not sure if you can can query Google maps api or Open Street Map like this.  The nice thing about your own map server is that you can completely define the map you want on it in one place.  Aside from this, I would browse the npm repository to see if anyone has tackled this problem before.